# Is it possible to execute AppKit functions with node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, cocoa, appkit

I was wondering if there is anyway to execute functions like `NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications()` from Apple's AppKit API in Node, or in general any function from [AppKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/core_app)

This might be a dumb question, and have some really obvious reason why it won't work I was just wondering if it was possible.

Comment: Well there's [this](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), so if you have a binary you can run, you can do it from node.

Comment: It'd be wayyy easier **IF** there is an npm package, keyword if.

Comment: That sounds like you're `asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource`, which is off-topic for this website.

Comment: Well, Im more asking if it is either possible to run AppKit function or if there already exists such npm packages, which I'd consider is still valid for StackOverflow.

Comment: I'll likely just make a shell script, or similar anyway, but again if an npm package existed that'd be very nice...